# Nginx rewrite URL

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get the `user-name` and `account_id`(the number at the end in the example '1') out of this url

> http://abc.com/desinger/user-name_1.html

I have tried this rule but I can't get the `account_id`

```
rewrite ^/desinger/(.+)_([0-9]+)$ /index.php?m=USER&hdn_account_id=$2 last;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 rewrite ^/desinger/(.+)_([0-9]+)$ /index.php?m=USER&hdn_account_id=$2 last;
```

you're missing the .html in your regex, it should be

```
 rewrite ^/desinger/(.+)_([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?m=USER&hdn_account_id=$2 last;
```